# Function to generate flight trajectory (list of 3D points, lat, lon, alt)

Tags: c#, python, algorithm, flightpath

I am looking to generate some 3D trajectory data for an aircraft simulation.
The idea is that the aircraft takes off at some location `x` and continues to ascend at some average ascent velocity `a_v` and angle `a_theta` until it reaches a maximum altitude `m_a`. The aircraft would then continue at its `m_a` until it reaches a certain distance `d_d` from its destination, at which point it will begin its descent at some angle `d_theta` with an average descent velocity of `d_v`. Finally, the aircraft lands at destination `y`.

I would like the function to return a list of 3D points.

I am looking to implement this in either Python (preferred) or C#.

For illustration purposes:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Is there perhaps some open source project which does this? I have been looking for a while now, but have not found anything.

Comment: So where's the problem? For the diagram you've shown, `cos`, `sin`, `sqrt` and `**2` should be all that you need in addition to `+-*/`. Try to solve the problem in 2D first (as shown) and convert the coordinates to spherical. Also, if you only need a trajectory with 3D points, the velocity should be irrelevant.

Comment: Can the aircraft land / take off at any altitude?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Well, I suppose if I had the altitudes of airport A and B, then yes. It would be nice to take that into consideration.

Comment: And by the way, you can't specify both `d_d` and `d_theta`; either one is enough to calculate the trajectory for a given `m_a`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to solve the problem in 2 independent steps so that the airplane does not pass through the ground :

1. Calculate the path on the surface of a sphere.
2. Interpolate the height along this path.

For 1. you can use the [spherical interpolation techniques on Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp#Source_Code).

```
Quaternion slerp(Quaternion v0, Quaternion v1, double t) {
    // Only unit quaternions are valid rotations.
    // Normalize to avoid undefined behavior.
    v0.normalize();
    v1.normalize();

    // Compute the cosine of the angle between the two vectors.
    double dot = dot_product(v0, v1);

    const double DOT_THRESHOLD = 0.9995;
    if (fabs(dot) > DOT_THRESHOLD) {
        // If the inputs are too close for comfort, linearly interpolate
        // and normalize the result.

        Quaternion result = v0 + t*(v1 – v0);
        result.normalize();
        return result;
    }

    // If the dot product is negative, the quaternions
    // have opposite handed-ness and slerp won't take
    // the shorter path. Fix by reversing one quaternion.
    if (dot < 0.0f) {
        v1 = -v1;
        dot = -dot;
    }  

    Clamp(dot, -1, 1);           // Robustness: Stay within domain of acos()
    double theta_0 = acos(dot);  // theta_0 = angle between input vectors
    double theta = theta_0*t;    // theta = angle between v0 and result 

    Quaternion v2 = v1 – v0*dot;
    v2.normalize();              // { v0, v2 } is now an orthonormal basis

    return v0*cos(theta) + v2*sin(theta);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write any code, so I won't write any either. Python with [`math`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) package is more than enough to solve this problem.

Required steps:

- The plane should fly on a [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle). This means you only need [one distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) to describe X and Y.
- You could place the origin at X and specify Y with a latitude.
- Calculate the tangent of the Earth at X, and rotate by `a_theta`. Find the point where it reaches `m_a` altitude.
- Calculate the tangent of the Earth at Y, and rotate by `d_theta`. Find the point where it reaches `m_a` altitude.
- Draw an arc between the two previous points, with a radius of `EarthRadius + m_a`
- Every coordinate is known in the 2D of the great circle, you just need to rotate them back to 3D coordinates.

For a list of 3D points, you don't need either `a_v`, `d_v` or `d_d`.